# How can I distribute objects along a semicircumference in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to place small circles equaly distant along a semicircunference. Inkscape provides basic options to distribute horizontally and vertically, but can I do along a path, or in this case (if it's more easy) along a semicircunference?

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is to use radial clones, for cloning the small objects/circles around a common center, creating a circle of objects, and then deleting half of the circle, and "uncloning" the remaining objects.

It allows you to choose exactly how many clones you want in a full circle of 360 degrees.

Here is a video that shows how to make radial clones: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0I51hXCdvE

In short:

1. change the center of rotation of the object (the small circle), to set it in the center of the big imaginary circle, around which the objects will be cloned.
2. select your small circle, go to Edit > Clone > Create tiled clones
3. Clone settings: 1 row, 20 columns (or however duplications you need on a full circle)
4. In Shift tab: per row, set shiftX to -100%, per column set shiftY to -100%
5. In Rotation tab: per column: 360 divided by 20 (or your number) = 18 degrees.
6. Click Create

Undo and adapt settings if necessary.

Comment: I had to use column shiftX = -100% and no shiftY and no row shift

Comment: This answer worked, with @altschuler's shift settings

Comment: I also had to uncheck "Use saved size and position of the tile"

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pattern on Path extension or the likewise named live path effect.

http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-PatternAlongPath.html
http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-GenerateFromPath.html#Extensions-PatternAlongPath

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on [Tricks](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Tiles-Tricks.html) from the [Inkscape Manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/index.html) by Tavmjong Bah.

1. Click the object twice to get rotation handles (or once and Shift+S).
2. While holding Ctrl, left mouse drag the [Rotation Center](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html#RotationCenter) down.
3. Open the [Create Tiled Clones](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Tiles.html) dialog (custom assigned to Ctrl+Shift+I in my keyboard preferences).
4. On the [Shift Tab](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Tiles-Shift.html), check the "Exclude tile" checkbox under the "Per column" heading.
5. On the [Rotation Tab](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Tiles-Rotation.html), set "Rows, columns" to 1 x 6 and the "Per column" angle to 360° / 6 = 60° to generate 6 duplicates on a full circle.

Hit the "Create" button.

See ["Use saved size and position of the tile" at DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Use+saved+size+and+position+of+the+tile%22&t=canonical&atb=v230-1&ia=web) for documentation on that setting.