# Inkscape: Add 90°-lines around arc?

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way to add a certain amount of lines at a 90°-angle to a arc?

Crudely demonstrated using Paint.NET with red lines.

It's important to me that I can add any amount of lines, with the same exact distance between each one of them.[image]

Comment: Related question: [How can I distribute objects along a semicircumference in Inkscape?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/how-can-i-distribute-objects-along-a-semicircumference-in-inkscape)

Answer (score 1):

First change the rotation point of the object to the center of the arc's circle. Then go to "Edit > Clone > Create tiled clones". Choose the number of clones as columns, then choose the degree to rotate by under Rotation. The degree should be the portion of the circle the arc covers divided by the number of copies.